# ffmpeg how to select the audio channel with the biggest bps?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I have mp4 file with below format,

`$ ffprobe -i 70_1.mp4 -hide_banner
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '70_1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2018-10-30T08:57:38.000000Z
  Duration: 00:13:55.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2246 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m/bt709/unknown, progressive), 1440x1920, 2118 kb/s, 58.75 fps, 60 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-10-30T08:57:38.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : 'avc1'
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-10-30T08:57:38.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
    Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 119 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-10-30T08:57:38.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio`

As the auto channel is special, there is no sound when play in the browser.

So I use ffmpeg to transfer it with `ffmpeg -i 70_1.mp4 -crf 30 -b:a 23k -b:v 96k -threads 4 -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -y ooo.mp4`, the generated mp4 file can play in the browser.

`$ ffprobe.exe ooo.mp4 -hide_banner
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'ooo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.17.101
  Duration: 00:13:55.79, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 246 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1440x1920, 209 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 23 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio`

But there is one issue, I need to process mp4 file with many formats, some with 1 audio channel, some with 2, So I want to know how to select the audio channel with the biggest bps.

Comment: There's no automatic way. You'll have to run ffprobe to get bitrates and them compare them: `ffprobe -i "video.avi" -select_streams a -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v 0`

Comment: There are a few potential problems with your command line. You are specifying two different video encoding methods: `-crf 30  -b:v 96k` choose one or the other. In fact, choose `-crf 30` and drop the `-b:v 96k`. 96k (that's per second) for a video a little under 60FPS is crazy. The original is shown as: `2118 kb/s`. Lastly, FFMPEG/FFPROBE are not reliable for obtaining audio bitrates, some audio codecs will not display the bitrate or display 0.

Comment: It's unfair to downvoe without reason.